# Trigger: Find out the name of the object the trigger is firing for?

Tags: apex, trigger, custom-metadata, sobjecttype

Is it possible for the trigger to see the name of the object it's firing for? Say can I make the OpportunityTrigger be aware that the object name it's firing for is `Opportunity` without hardcoding the object name in the code?

**EDIT**

I want to use Custom Metadata to make `Object_To_Track_mdt`. Once a trigger fires I want to use the object name the trigger is firing for to see if the object needs to be tracked or not. Here's a very rough code sample I have in mind:

```
Object_To_Track__mdt trackedObject = [
                SELECT Id, 
                (SELECT Id FROM Fields_To_Track__r) 
                FROM Object_To_Track__mdt
                WHERE DeveloperName='Lead'
];
if (trackedObject  != null && trackedObject.Fields_To_Track__r.size() > 0) {
    // Verify if the modified fields for Lead need to be tracked or not.
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't care about the `delete` contexts, you can just do:

```
SObjectType triggerType = trigger.new.getSObjectType();
```

It doesn't add much complexity, however, to use a ternary to check for the null case:

```
SObjectType triggerType = trigger.isDelete ? 
    trigger.old.getSObjectType() :
    trigger.new.getSObjectType();
```